# How to block until one of two Receivers has available data?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and trying to set up a one-directional graph of nodes using `Sender`s and `Receiver`s from `std::sync::mpsc`. Right now I have it working when each node has exactly one parent and one child, like this:

```
fn run(mut self) {
    let parent = self.parent.unwrap();
    loop {
        match parent.recv() {
            Ok(input) => {
                self.value = (self.next_value)(input);
                match self.kid {
                    Some(ref k) => { k.send(self.value).unwrap(); },
                    None => {}
                }
            },
            Err(_) => {}
        }
    }

}
```

But what I really want to do is have two parent nodes, where the `next_value` function is evaluated and the child nodes notified whenever *either* parent node sends out another value. I can't just use the blocking `recv()` method twice, and using polling and a non-blocking `try_recv()` call would probably work, but it seems really inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`select!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/macro.select!.html)

```
fn run(mut self) {
    // obtain parents
    loop {
        select! {
           resp = parent1.recv() => match resp {...}
           resp = parent2.recv() => match resp {...}
        }
    }

}
```

If you have a dynamic number of channels to receive on, use [`mpsc::Select`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Select.html)